# Trace.WriteLine() with TextWriterTraceListener eventually stops working on a published ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, trace

I'm adding logging using `Trace` to a new ASP.NET site.  When I run the project locally, the logging works as expected.  When I publish the project (via a file system publish through Visual Studio), the site will successfully log for a little while (anywhere from a few seconds to several minutes), but then eventually stop writing to the output file.

Here's how I'm initializing my `TraceListener` in my `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{  
    textWriterTL = new TextWriterTraceListener(logFilePath);
    Trace.Listeners.Add(textWriterTL);
    Trace.AutoFlush = true;

    ...
}
```

Later, in a Web API controller method, I write to `Trace` like so:

```
Trace.WriteLine("An error occurred").
```

I don't feel like I'm doing anything unconventional.  Why does my site stop logging after a period of time?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in the `Application_Start` method you souldn't instance any class, according to MSDN docs:

> You should set only static data during application start. Do not set
>   any instance data because it will be available only to the first
>   instance of the HttpApplication class that is created.

I recommend set the TraceListener in Web.config, just like this sample:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" name="FileListener" initializeData="MyLog.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx